# click in JavaScript does not work by custom click event

Tags: javascript, click

I want to generate a click event on a button in the iFrame, the console message says that it has found the button, and it has clicked on it, but I see nothing happens.
If I click by hand on the drop down arrow in the iframe, it will show a popup menu, but if I call the runExcel() function from the parent frame, it will show that it is clicked, but it can not find the popup contents. Maybe the button in the iframe uses custom click event? if so, are there any other methods to generate a real click on the button? (I have tried click event, it does not work either.)

[image: drop down arrow]

[image: Popup menu]

Here is my code:

```js
function runExcel() {
  var iframe= document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
  var Report0 = iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
  var Report1 = iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1].contentWindow;

  // Find the dropdown arrow element
 const dropdownArrow = Report0.document.querySelector('#AppToolbarLeftPane_btnRun_dropdown');
  console.log('Dropdown arrow element:', dropdownArrow);

  console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', {Report0});
  console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', Report0.document);
  console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', {dropdownArrow});

  // Click on the dropdown arrow to open the menu
  if (!!dropdownArrow) {
    dropdownArrow.click();
    console.log('Clicked dropdown arrow');
    
    // Find the "Run Excel" menu item
    setTimeout(() => {
      const runExcelItem = Report0.document.querySelector('#mnuAppToolbarLeftPaneRun_spreadsheetML');
      console.log('"Run Excel" menu item:', runExcelItem);

      // Click on the "Run Excel" menu item to run the report
      if (!!runExcelItem) {
        runExcelItem.click();
        console.log('Clicked "Run Excel" menu item');
      } else {
        console.log('Could not find "Run Excel" menu item');
      }
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    console.log('Could not find dropdown arrow');
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" role="button" onclick="runExcel();">runExcel</button>
```

---

Console:

```
Dropdown arrow element: <td class=​"clsToolbarButton" id=​"AppToolbarLeftPane_btnRun_dropdown" _ppk=​"1" title=​"Run actions" hal_tooltipposition=​"bottom" _28g=​"mnuAppToolbarLeftPaneRunPopup" bshowspopup=​"true" bshowsdialog=​"true" style=​"display:​ none;​">​…​</td>​
disp:249 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {Report0: Window}
disp:250 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #document
disp:251 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {dropdownArrow: td#AppToolbarLeftPane_btnRun_dropdown.clsToolbarButton}
disp:256 Clicked dropdown arrow
disp:261 "Run Excel" menu item: null
disp:268 Could not find "Run Excel" menu item
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us by editing your question? Seeing the button click event handler & the iframe would help us understand your question

Comment: Hi, please see my question, I just edited it. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to provide a jsfiddle or similar because as it stands your code doesn't even compile let alone run

Comment: Are all these iframes on the same domain?

Comment: yes, from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be written like this:

```
let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
iframe.onload = function() {
//your function/code here
};
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: Hi, please see my attached console results print screen in my question (link at the end). It says it has found the SVG, and also clicked on it.

Comment: @Frank 
It looks like you need to show html. Otherwise, it is not clear why you find iframe[0] and then look again for iframe[0] in it.
Do you REALLY have multiple iframes on the page and you have two more iframes in the first one???

Comment: Hi, in the iframe there is an app bar, that is the first frame, and then the drop down arrow is in the second frame. This is a web application, it is not a website. I think the contents of the menu are not loaded yet from the server before the drop-down arrow is clicked.  When the click is simulated by JavaScript, but the drop-down arrow is not fired, so it can not tell the server, so the drop-down menu and contents can not be shown.

Comment: @Frank Hmm... so you have a function to load data from the server. Then you can call it from runExcel(), and in order for the list to open, you can add an attribute to the arrow.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me the reason? There are attributes in the arrow.

Comment: @Frank
Perhaps I'm not too precise in the wording (English is not my native language, sorry), I'm just not experienced enough to fully understand what you are trying to accomplish.
You have the "Run Excel" button in the drop-down list. Attached to this button is a function that finds '#mnuAppToolbarLeftPaneRun_spreadsheetML', which seems to be a drop-down menu with a "Run Excel" button. In this case, you generate 2 click events on the menu itself, and not on the button, but in consol.log you refer to the "Run Excel" button. Also with pauses :) The meaning of all these actions eludes me.

Comment: And if you don't have another "Run Excel" button outside of the dropdown menu, then you really don't need to change the dropdown menu attributes. After all, to click on "Run Excel" you are already in the drop-down menu.
But if you click on "Run Excel" in one frame and want (for some reason) to multiply this click on the second "Run Excel" button in the drop-down menu, then your dispatchEvent needs to be targeted not at the menu, but at the button.
Although, as I wrote earlier, it's easier not to generate an event, but to load data from the server in runExcel ().

Comment: Hi, I have updated my script and console, the point here is: the JavaScript can find the drop down arrow and click on it, but there is no trigger on it, there will not show a popup menu with Run Excel item in.

Comment: Hello, @Frank
Something like a bot or interface self-test?
When inspecting the "arrow", is the ID really the same as what you are looking for?
Notice that you didn't even find the runExcelItem button. In the console null !
Try in the inspector to copy the path to the arrow and the button in the dropdown menu. Show what you find. And in console.log(), please don't use curly braces.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if the menu were display: none , the button would still be pressed. If correctly found/loaded.

Comment: The problem here is: the contents of the popup is not loaded yet, it can only be loaded by clicking on the drop-down arrow by hand. It uses maybe custom event, JavaScript can simulate a click, but it can not trigger the event. So there will be no drop down menu contents be loaded from the server.

Comment: The purpose of the function is that I just need click once on the button in parent frame to open run Excel instead of twice by hand in the iframe (first on the arrow, then on Run Excel). So it will decrease clicks every day. That is good for health.

Comment: @Frank
I have an idea. I have edited my answer. Check.
After the discussion, it became clear that you need to wait for the frame to fully load. It is worth using .onload, and when the frame is fully loaded, you can already search for elements, trigger events.

Comment: The iframe is already loaded, only the contents of the drop-down menu is not loaded yet. After clicking on the drop-down arrow, then it will communicate with the server and load the contents of the drop-down menu. The page itself will not reload again.

Comment: @Frank
Then consider using MutationObserver. When using an observer, you can track all changes to the drop-down menu and more. You need to carefully examine what attributes appear on menu items. Knowing what needs to be tracked is a matter of technology.

Comment: I found if I click once on the drop down arrow, and let the drop down menu on, then I use the runExcel() function, it works and then open a new link to run the report,  because I think at this moment the contents of the dropdown are in the DOM, but if I click on the drop down arrow, and the drop down menu disappears, at this moment if i use the runExcel() function, it still does not work, that is very strange, because all the contents are in DOM, and it shows Clicked "Run Excel" menu item, but no action is returned.

Comment: @Frank
This is really weird :)
Since in your function there must first be a click on the arrow. So, the menu should close, since it is already open. But I understand that this did not happen. And your menu is not in the shadow DOM, by any chance?

Comment: I mean if I click the drop-down arrow by hand once, then it will communicate with the server and fetch the menu contents, and the drop-down menu will be shown . And at this moment I call the runExcel function, it will work.